# multiple markers at set iterator

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, set

```
class FileObject
{
public:
set<string> owners;
.
.
.
};
```

in this function I have problem with this line:for(std::set it = owners.begin(); it != owners.end(); it++).

```
void FileObject::viewFileDetails(string* messageToPrint)
{
    *messageToPrint = fileName;
    *messageToPrint += ", ";
    if(status == 0)
    {
        *messageToPrint += convertInt(countVersion);
    }
    else
    {
        *messageToPrint += userCheckedOut;
    }
    *messageToPrint += " (owners: ";
    unsigned int i=0;

    for(std::set<string> it = owners.begin(); it != owners.end(); it++)
    {
        *messageToPrint += *it;
        if( i != owners.size())
        {
            *messageToPrint += ", ";
        }
        else
        {
            *messageToPrint += ")";
        }
        i++;
    }

}
```

**this is the error:**

> Multiple markers at this line
>       - 'std::set >' is not derived from 'const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_IteratorL, _Container>'
>       - no 'operator++(int)' declared for postfix '++' [-fpermissive]
>       - 'std::set >' is not derived from 'const std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>'
>       - 'std::set >' is not derived from 'const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>'
>       - 'std::set >' is not derived from 'const std::_Rb_tree_iterator<_Tp>'
>       - 'std::set >' is not derived from 'const std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>'
>       - 'std::set >' is not derived from 'const std::_List_iterator<_Tp>'
>       - 'std::set >' is not derived from 'const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>'
>       - 'std::set >' is not derived from 'const __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>'
>       - 'std::set >' is not derived from 'const std::multiset<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>'
>       - 'std::set >' is not derived from 'const std::istream_iterator<_Tp, _CharT, _Traits, _Dist>'
>       - 'std::set >::iterator {aka std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator >}' is not derived from 'const 
>        std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>'
>       - 'std::set >' is not derived from 'const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>'
>       - 'std::set >' is not derived from 'const std::pair<_T1, _T2>'
>       - 'std::set >' is not derived from 'const std::fpos<_StateT>'
>       - candidates are:
>       - conversion from 'std::set >::iterator {aka std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator >}' to non-scalar 
>        type 'std::set >' requested
>       - no match for 'operator!=' (operand types are 'std::set >' and 'std::set >::iterator {aka 
>        std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator >}')
>       - 'std::set >' is not derived from 'const std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT, _Traits>'
>       - mismatched types 'const _CharT*' and 'std::set >'
>       - 'std::set >' is not derived from 'const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>'
>       - 'std::set >' is not derived from 'const std::allocator<_CharT>'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of `it` should be `set<string>::const_iterator` or `set<string>::iterator`, not `set<string>`.

If you're using C++11, you can just use `auto`. :-)

Also, as a matter of style, prefer to return your `messageToPrint` by value, rather than using an out parameter.